# PHP dynamic list pick values in next page

Tags: php, mysql, list, dynamic, insert

Am trying to insert values from a php generated option list into a mysql database. The error i am getting in a "notice error". The error reads:

> Notice: Undefined index: fixture_id in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\insert.php on line 177
>
> Notice: Undefined index: goalkeeper in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\insert.php on line 178
>
> Notice: Undefined index: defender in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\insert.php on line 179
>
> Notice: Undefined index: fullback in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\insert.php on line 180
>
> Notice: Undefined index: midfielder in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\insert.php on line 181
>
> Notice: Undefined index: wing in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\insert.php on
>   line 182
>
> Notice: Undefined index: striker in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\insert.php
>   on line 183

My code is given below. I am an intermediate developer and developing a team management system.

```
 elseif(isset($_GET['selection_id'])){ // check if form is submitted
   echo "<table><form name=\"insertSelectionForm\" action=\"". $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\" method=\"post\">";
    echo"<tr bgcolor=\"#ccc\"><td colspan=\"2\">Add selection</td></tr>";
    echo"<tr><td>Fixture Id</td><td><select name=\"fixtures[]\">";

    $sql = "SELECT fixture_id FROM `fixtures` ";
    $data = mysql_query($sql);
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
                echo "<option name=\"fixture_id\" value={$rows['fixture_id']} >";
                echo $rows['fixture_id'];
                echo "</option>\n";
            }

    echo "</select>\n";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo"<tr><td>Goalkeeper</td><td><select>";
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM `player` ";
    $data = mysql_query($sql);
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
                echo "<option name=\"goalkeeper\" value={$rows['name']}>";
                echo $rows['name'];
                echo "</option>";
            }

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo"<tr><td>Defender</td><td><select>";

    $sql = "SELECT name FROM `player` ";
    $data = mysql_query($sql);
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
                echo "<option name=\"defender\" value={$rows['name']}>";
                echo $rows['name'];
                echo "</option>";
            }

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Fullback</td><td><select>";

    $sql = "SELECT name FROM `player` ";
    $data = mysql_query($sql);
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
                echo "<option name=\"fullback\" value={$rows['name']}>";
                echo $rows['name'];
                echo "</option>";
            }

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo"<tr><td>Midfielder</td><td><select>";

    $sql = "SELECT name FROM `player` ";
    $data = mysql_query($sql);
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
                echo "<option name=\"midfielder\" value={$rows['name']}>";
                echo $rows['name'];
                echo "</option>";
            }

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo"<tr><td>Wing</td><td><select>";

    $sql = "SELECT name FROM `player` ";
    $data = mysql_query($sql);
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
                echo "<option name=\"wing\" value={$rows['name']}>";
                echo $rows['name'];
                echo "</option>";
            }

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo"<tr><td>Striker</td><td><select>";


    $sql = "SELECT name FROM `player` ";
    $data = mysql_query($sql);
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
                echo "<option name=\"striker\" value={$rows['name']}>";
                echo $rows['name'];
                echo "</option>";
            }

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo"<tr><td></td><td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add Selection\" name=\"selection\"></td></tr>";
    echo "</table></form>";
}


elseif(isset($_POST['selection'])){
            //collect variables posted by form.
            $fixture_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fixture_id']);
            $goalkeeper = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['goalkeeper']);
            $defender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['defender']);
            $fullback = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fullback']);
            $midfielder = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['midfielder']);
            $wing = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['wing']);
            $striker = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['striker']);

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM fixtures WHERE fixture_id = '$fixture_id'";
            $data = mysql_query($sql);
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
            $opponents = $rows['opponents'];    
        }



    //validate form by checking for empty strings that user might have submitted using strlen() php built-in method. If no empty string form processes
         if(strlen($fixture_id)>0 && strlen($goalkeeper)>0 && strlen($defender)>0 && strlen($fullback)>0 && strlen($midfielder)>0 && strlen($wing)>0 && strlen($striker)>0 ){ // if form fields are not empty, insert in database
                $sql = "INSERT into `selections` (fixture_id, opponents, goalkeeper,defender,fullback,midfielder,wing,striker) VALUES('$fixture_id','$opponents', '$goalkeeper','$defender','$fullback','$midfielder','$wing','$striker')";
                $query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error. ". mysql_error()) ;
                echo "Selection added <br/><br/>";
                echo " <a href=\"team_selections.php\">Go back to team selections page </a>";
            }

        }
```

Comment: notice!=error is the code still working?

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index` means that you are trying to use an array key, ie. `$_POST['striker']`, that does not exist or has not been set yet.

Comment: No the code is not inserting in the form. The reason i am building the list dynamically is because i dont want the user to enter values of players which are not already loaded by the coach. The code is not even inserting anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrongly interpreted `name` attribute in `<select>`. You have to give name attributes like

`<select name=\"fixture_id\">` and not in `<option name="fixture_id">`

So remove name attribute from `<option>` (remove it from `<option>`) and specify it in `<select>`

Comment: Lovely. Works same time. Thanks and God bless. Error was exactly where you pointed out. Spent the last 2 hours changing the code not knowing the error was there. God bless you. Charles South Africa :)

Comment: It's good that it has solved your problem. And if it's resolved then you can mark as Resolved

Answer (score 1):

You set `name` attribute to select element options. but to send data to script, you mast set name for `<select>` tag, not `<option>`. Option must have value attribute only.

Answer (score 1):

@NullVoid & @Eugene identified the biggest issue, but your `<form>` is also invaild as it cannot be child of `<table>`

```
echo "<table><form name=\"insertSelectionForm\" action=\"". $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\" method=\"post\">";
      ^^^     ^^^^
```

`<form>` tags need to either surround the table - `<form><table>...</table></form>` or reside inside a cell - `<table><tr><td><form>...</form></td></tr></table>`

try switching to -

```
echo "<form name=\"insertSelectionForm\" action=\"". $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\" method=\"post\"><table>";
```

Comment: Thanks also for that point. Nullvoid's solution worked. I will also take note of the form issue so that i conform to the right standards

Comment: +1 for suggestion about `<form>` should be outside `<table>` to meet standard and correct way.